# Unity text on cube prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures

I want to make a cube in Unity3D which can move and jump etc.... and I want to generate a random number (1-99). I want the number to be on the cube's every side. I don't want to make 99 texture I want to add the number with script. I read that I should add Text Mesh but i cant because I have Mesh Renderer.

Can somebody help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerThings : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int player_name;

    void Start () {
        player_name = Random.Range (10, 99);
        name = player_name.ToString();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing is in your Update function, get rid of it. It's still being called every fraction of a second to check there is nothing in it. If this is persistent in your code a lot, it will eventually unnecessarily slow it down.

Next - A solution is to add an empty GameObject, whose children are the sides of your cube which require a Text Mesh.
Place each of the children in an array, and then do a foreach:

```
foreach(textarray as GameObject ta){
ta.getComponent<TextMesh>().text = name;
}
```

Comment: Work! Thank you! :)

Comment: @antal1208 Anytime! Please accept the answer and upvote if applicable also. Just to save others thinking it's still an open question.